# cordova-android 11 :: Could not find com.google.xy

Tags: android-studio, cordova

After updating to cordova-android 11.0.0, the Android build fails with the following error(s):

I have tried everything possible, but am at a loss...

```
   > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.3.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/20.3.0/play-services-auth-20.3.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/20.3.0/play-services-auth-20.3.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:20.3.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-identity/20.3.0/play-services-identity-20.3.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-identity/20.3.0/play-services-identity-20.3.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
```

build.gradle:

```
  buildscript {
    apply from: 'CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
    apply from: 'repositories.gradle'
    repositories repos
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:${cordovaConfig.AGP_VERSION}"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${cordovaConfig.KOTLIN_VERSION}"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
    cdvHelpers.verifyCordovaConfigForBuild()
  }
```

repositories.gradle:

```
ext.repos = {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

cordova.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.github.g00fy2:versioncompare:1.4.1@jar'
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

It was an old plugin which caused the errors.